# MOSS 2007 SP2 Upgrade - is Rebuild Index mendatory

Tags: upgrade

I am preparing for MOSS 2007 SP2 upgrade for my client (quite late though).

I am following [SP2 - Step By Step](http://blogs.architectingconnectedsystems.com/blogs/cjg/archive/2009/05/10/How-to-upgrade-to-SharePoint-2007-SP2-_2D00_-Step-by-Step.aspx) article.

I am just curious if it is mendatory (or advisable) to rebuild the DB index before the upgrade?

Please suggest...

Answer (score 1):

It isn't mandatory, but as upgrading is very database intensive it may be a good idea to limit the downtime during the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks Per,  my SharePoint 2007 environment is not that hug,  it has just one site collection and 3-4 content databases.